# Allow users to reorder multiple different objects together

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need some concept help. I have an app that has multiple clocks, a date, and a message, and the user needs to be able to reorder these items in any way.

For the clocks, they can add any number of clocks including having no clocks. For this I collect an array of clocks. And then I have a single Date object that is displayed and a single Message object.

Below is a basic example of the settings I have for each of these, and I can add to this if needed to make this work:

```
clocks: [
  {
    clockLabel: 'My clock',
    ...etc...
  },
  {
    clockLabel: 'My second clock',
    ...etc...
  }
],
theDate: [
  enabled: true,
  showYear: true,
  ...etc...
],
customMessage: [
  enabled: true,
  text: 'My custom message',
  ...etc...
]
```

I need to figure out a way that all these elements can be rearranged among each other so that it could be possible to have for example, 2 clocks then the date then another clock and then the message.

The idea here is that in the settings a user can click an up or down arrow for each item to move it up or down in the list of all items.

I was thinking of maybe having a separate array that I can track each item in and reorder that array, but for that I think I would need to add an ID to each clock to keep it tied to the correct clock in the sort array and would need to remove it from that array when a clock is deleted, but I'm not sure if this would be my best option.

For actual display on the page I was planning on using the CSS order property with flexbox to display them in the order the user determines.

EDIT: Should also note that I need to be able to save the order somewhere so the next time the app gets loaded it returns to the order the user set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could introduce `position` property in every object so that you don't have to manage new array to know about the position of current object

Below I have created `showPositionedResults` method to return sorted array by `position` and `changePosition` method to change element position by `+- 1` when user clicks on up and down arrow.

```js
let clocks = [
  {
    clockLabel: 'My clock',
    position: 1
  },
  {
    clockLabel: 'My second clock',
    position: 2
  }
],
theDate = [
  {
    enabled: true,
    showYear: true,
    position: 3
  }
],
customMessage = [
  {
    enabled: true,
    text: 'My custom message',
    position: 4
  }
]

let combinedResult = [...clocks, ...theDate, ...customMessage]

let originalCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(combinedResult))

// show sorted results by position
function showPositionedResults() {
  return combinedResult.sort((a,b) => a.position - b.position)
}

console.log(showPositionedResults())

// change position by +- 1
function changePosition(position, up) {
  let el = combinedResult.find(d => d.position == position)
  if(up) {
    combinedResult.find(d => d.position == position-1).position += 1
    el.position -= 1
  } else {
    combinedResult.find(d => d.position == position+1).position -= 1
    el.position += 1
  }
}

// increase position 4 to 3
changePosition(4, true)
console.log(showPositionedResults())

// decrease position 1 to 2
changePosition(1, false)
console.log(showPositionedResults())

// original copy
console.log(originalCopy)
```

Comment: I think I'll need to change my structure a lot to get this fully working, but so far with a quick attempt I think this is what I needed! One question though, I don't see how this can save the position back to the original data? Is that possible?

Comment: @BlueCaret Edited code above to save `originalCopy` with initial position of records. Pls check if it answers your query.

Comment: Sorry, I meant change the adjusted position back to the original arrays before combining, not create a new array. But I think I might see how to do it but I'll have to mess with it some. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the initial position of the items is maintained in a separate array by using the index of the items:

```
let position = [0, 1, 2, 3];
```

Now, when the user presses the up arrow on the third item (`index == 2`), you know that you have to shift the third item in the position array one position up. (You can determine whose up arrow was pressed based on the index of the displayed item on the screen, rather than directly querying it from the `ITEMS` array. That makes sure you don't need a separate ID field.)

```
position = [0, 2, 1, 3];
```

So, whenever the second item **on the screen** is pressed, you know that you have to shift the `position` array's second (`index == 1`) element upwards/downwards.

Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: How would this allow me to put the date in between two clocks for example? I see how this would work for just reordering the clocks, but not for how to get the date and message to get reordered with the clocks since they are not in the same array as each individual clock. Thanks

Comment: I should also note that I need to be able to save this position so next time the app is loaded it returns to the order the user set.